# `__self` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I want to use Rust to implement a simple command&control server. The project is https://github.com/wilbyang/c2server
There are 3 components in it, the server component is the controller, the admin component issues instructions and retrieves the results of the instructions, and the implant component is a victim machine. The interaction is as follows

[image]

The part in the ellipse 3 gRPC calls. There are 2 queues inside the server and two parts one is AdminService and the other ImplantService. In my implementation, there are two members inside AdminService struct, which are the tx reference of mpsc-1 and the rx reference of mpsc-2. I need to use self.rx to receive messages in the implementation of gRPC, so rx must be a mut reference, but the gRPC method stub, self is a general reference. So I get the error `__self` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable.

The corresponding code is the `Ok(())` arm here:

```
#[tonic::async_trait]
impl Admin for AdminService {
    async fn run_command(&self, request: Request<Command>) -> Result<Response<Command>, Status> {
        let cmd = request.into_inner();
        match self.tx.send(cmd.clone()).await {
            Ok(()) => match self.rx.recv().await {
                Some(cmd) => Ok(Response::new(cmd.clone())),
                None => todo!(),
            },
            Err(_) => todo!(),
        }
    }
}
```

([Source](https://github.com/wilbyang/c2server/blob/c2ba2d91b0b1c1a26f30d7e7454bd241da22736a/src/server.rs#L54))

Comment: `&mut self` perhaps?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to show just the minimized code. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.